# EntityFrameworkCore generates empty migrations

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am using EFCore 3 code-first approach with migrations. Created new database in MySQL 5.7 and applied old migrations using `dotnet ef database update`. All tables were created and `__EFMigrationsHistory` has records.
Then I added `[MaxLength(2000)]` to the `RepairHistory.comment` field.

Before creating migration, `ContextModelSnapshot` contains this definition:

```
b.Property<string>("Comment")
    .HasColumnName("comment")
    .HasColumnType("varchar(1000)")
    .HasAnnotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8")
    .HasAnnotation("MySql:Collation", "utf8_unicode_ci");
```

#### Expected behavior:

Calling `dotnet ef migrations add ExtendComment` will create migration files with changing column type to `"varchar(2000)"`, `ContextModelSnapshot` will change row `.HasColumnType("varchar(1000)")` to `.HasColumnType("varchar(2000)")`.

#### Real behavior:

Calling `dotnet ef migrations add ExtendComment` creates **empty** migration files.
`ContextModelSnapshot` changes field defition in wrong way, instead of changing column type, it added `HasMaxLength`, that is higher than column type size.

```
b.Property<string>("Comment")
    .HasColumnName("comment")
    .HasColumnType("varchar(1000)")
    .HasMaxLength(2000)
    .HasAnnotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8")
    .HasAnnotation("MySql:Collation", "utf8_unicode_ci");
```

What I did wrong?